# File data null in File uploading using REST

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, rest, file-upload

And i have the following code

```
self.upload = function (file) {
            var path = $('#fileUpload').val();
           var fr= new FileReader();
            var ID = JSON.stringify({
               ID:23,
               Name: file.name,
               Type: file.type,
               Size: file.size,
               Path: path,
               data:fr.readAsDataURL(file),


            });

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                url: "http://localhost:49589/api/files",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                data: ID,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                processData: false,
                success: function (json) {
                            alert("Data Returned: " + JSON.stringify(json));
                        },
                error: function (json) {
                alert("error" + JSON.stringify(json));
            }

            });
```

im performing file upload . and my controller is

```
[HttpPost]
        public string upload(filesUpload f)
        {

            byte[] jj = f.data; // **getting null here** 
            string givenId = f.Path;
            return givenId;

        }
```

when i execute this and upload a file im getting null file data . where  **filesUpload**  is my model

what went wrong in my code . Im using Knockout.js  for viwe and drundal SPA framework

is there any other way to do .  kindly help me

Comment: `data:fr.readAsDataURL(file),` extra comma is there, may b it will be an issue

Answer (score 1):

**FileReader.readAsDataURL** [reads](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader#readAsDataURL%28%29) the file asyncronically and return nothing. You should at first start read the file, then catch fr.onload event and from here create your json object and call ajax.

**upd:** The code will look like this:

```
    self.upload = function (file) {
               var path = $('#fileUpload').val();
               var fr= new FileReader();
               fr.onload = function (frEvent) {
                     var ID = JSON.stringify({
                     ID:23,
                     Name: file.name,
                     Type: file.type,
                     Size: file.size,
                     Path: path,
                     data:frEvent.target.result,
                    });

                    $.ajax({
                      cache: false,
                      url: "http://localhost:49589/api/files",
                      type: "POST",
                      dataType: "json",
                      data: ID,
                      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      processData: false,
                      success: function (json) {
                                alert("Data Returned: " + JSON.stringify(json));
                            },
                      error: function (json) {
                       alert("error" + JSON.stringify(json));
                      }
                    });
                   };
                 fr.readAsDataURL(file);
            };
```