# Loading csv files content into dictionary of objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, csv

I'm trying to load the content of the several CSV files into a new array. CSV files have a typical structure, with a label in the first row, and values (both string and real numbers) separated by commas. This part of code is responsible for loading the data for future use with Google Maps Api (not a problem for now, since I'm stuck on just loading the data). I would like to have a structure, in which I could call an element by it's name, that's why the `var nodedata = {};` is created.

So the thing I totally don't get is why some part of the code is not being executed at all? `console.log(nodedata);` is empty, at least not in my Firefox console.

That's my attempt to the problem - links to the csv files are in the code.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://jquery-csv.googlecode.com/files/jquery.csv-0.71.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var nodes = {};
var generation = {};
var nodedata = {};

$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25575808/energy/nodes.csv', function (response) {
    nodes = $.csv.toObjects(response);
    console.log(nodes);
});

$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25575808/energy/generation.csv', function (response) {
generation = $.csv.toObjects(response);
console.log(generation);
});


function getGeneration (nodename){
    gen = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < generation.length; i++) {
    if (generation[i].datetime == "2013-01-01 01:00"){
        if (generation[i].node == nodename){
             gen = gen + Number(generation[i]["output (MW)"])
        }
    }
    }
    return gen;
}


for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    nodedata[nodes[i].Node] = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(nodes[i].Latitude,nodes[i].Longitude),
    nodegen : getGeneration(nodes[i].Node)
    }
}
console.log(nodedata);
```

Comment: i have faced a issue similar to this refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18912616/file-data-null-in-file-uploading-using-rest

Comment: So far I'm simply using a few static csv files - I thought I can do what I want with pure javascript? Or maybe I'm wrong? I managed to use the data loaded from those files, but in ugly manner full of loops - now I wanted to have a dictionary from which I could easily check the properties of nodes calling them by ID. Just to clarify - I'm really a JavaScript beginner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem you're having is unrelated to the usage of CSV data, rather it is the fact that the data is being loaded asynchronously.

You are executing 2 $.get() requests to load the files, which will take some time to download the files. The browser does not wait for them to finish before continuing through the rest of the code.

Therefore, it is possible for `console.log(nodedate)` to be executed before any data exists inside the `nodes` array.

An easy way to handle this is to stack your callback functions so that the first GET request completes -> run the 2nd GET request -> finally, run the processing code.

Check out this reorganization of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/Vr7sw/

(I removed the Google Maps line since I don't have the library loaded)

Comment: Clear and simple - it works, thank you a lot! I think I didn't get the whole idea of asynchronous execution.

Answer (score 1):

the problem is, the $.get requests are asynchronous (see [jquery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)), try to call to a function, into your callback body like this :

```
function nodesToJson(nodes) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
        nodedata[nodes[i].Node] = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(nodes[node].Latitude,nodes[node].Longitude),
        nodegen : getGeneration(nodes[i].Node)
        }
    }
    console.log(nodedata);
}
$.get('https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/25575808/energy/nodes.csv', function (response) {
    nodes = $.csv.toObjects(response);
    //when the request are ready, process the nodes
    nodesToJson(nodes);
});
```

Comment: It works as well, thank you. I need to understand the asynchronous loading better.